# Perl - Sorting In UNIX Different From Windows

Tags: perl, sorting, gnu

I'm having issues sorting in Perl having different results in Windows and Unix.

The characters are: a - _ 1 2

```
In Windows: _ 1 2 - a
In Unix: _ - 1 2 a
```

I'm guessing the locale has something to do with this - what can I do to make the Unix sort match the Windows sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

so use

```
LC_ALL=C sort ...
```

Example:

```
$ perl -E'say for @ARGV' a - _ 1 2 | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort
_
-
1
2
a

$ perl -E'say for @ARGV' a - _ 1 2 | LC_ALL=C sort
-
1
2
_
a
```

Comment: These are still not the same as the results in Windows.   I need it to match Windows' sort - is there a collation on Unix that will do this?

Comment: @Mike, oo, I see that Windows's uses a local too. Well, you'll have to find out what local your Windows uses and see if there's an equivalent one on your unix system, and use it instead of `C` as I showed. I wish you luck!

Comment: That seems to be where I'm at - English_United States.1252 seems to be the Windows one, but I can't yet find a Unix counterpart.

Comment: Originally, the following was a comment, but, for more exposure, I just made a new question out of my comment. I then erased the comment, because I don't want to have people answer it twice.  I originally addressed comment to @tchrist, because he strikes me as a guru on the matter.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013515/multilingual-text-sorting-in-perl-on-windows-using-locale

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use locale, comment out the line containing

```
use locale;
```

Without such a line, `sort` in Perl should behave the same on both Windows and Unix.

You can also add

```
no locale;
```

before the `sort` (or, better, enclose the sort into a block starting with it).

Comment: I don't have "use locale" in the scripts at all.

Comment: @Mike all it takes is one module using it to change it everywhere.

Comment: My script is not using any modules at all.  I tried no locale anyway with no changes.

Comment: @Mike: I'm getting the same results for `perl -le 'print sort qw/a - _ 1 2/'`.