# Sorting UTF-8 input

Tags: perl, utf-8

I need to sort lines from file, saved as UTF-8. These lines can start with cyrillic or latin characters. My code works wrong on cyrillic one.

```
sub sort_by_default  {
    my @sorted_lines = sort {
        $a <=> $b
          ||
        fc( $a) cmp fc($b)
     } @_;
}
```

Comment: How do you open the file? How do you read the lines?

Comment: What order do you expect for Latin versus Cyrillic words?

Comment: open(FILE, "$address") or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
my @file = <FILE>;
close (FILE);

Comment: in Latin versus my lines are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Which Perl version?

Comment: I use version 5.016

Comment: Where's the rest of the demonstration of the problem??? What problem are you having???

Answer (score 10):

The `cmp` used with `sort` can't help with this; it has no notion of encodings and merely compares by codepoint, character by character, with surprises in many languages. Use [Unicode::Collate](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esadahiro/Unicode-Collate-1.25/Collate.pm).<sup>†</sup> See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46617394/4653379) for a bit more and for far more [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013515/multilingual-text-sorting-in-perl-on-windows-using-locale/15016188#15016188) by tchrist and this [perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/pub/2011/08/whats-wrong-with-sort-and-how-to-fix-it.html/).

The other issue is of reading (decoding) input and writing (encoding) output in utf8 correctly. One way to ensure that data on standard streams is handled is via the [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html), with which you can set "layers" so that input and output is decoded/encoded as data is read/written.

Altogether, an example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Unicode::Collate;

use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my $file = ...;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;
chomp @lines;

my $uc  = Unicode::Collate->new();
my @sorted = $uc->sort(@lines);

say for @sorted;
```

The module's `cmp` method can be used for individual comparisons (if data
is in a complex data structure and not just a flat list of lines, for instance)

```
my @sorted = map { $uc->cmp($a, $b) } @data;
```

where `$a` and `$b` need be set suitably so to extract what to compare from `@data`.

If you have utf8 data right in the source you need `use utf8`, while if you receive utf8 via yet other channels (from `@ARGV` included) you may need to manually [Encode::decode](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) those strings.

Please see the linked post (and links in it) and documentation for more detail. See this [perlmonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=755158) for far more rounded information. See this [Effective Perler article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-sort-orders/) on custom sorting.

---

<sup>†</sup> Example: by codepoint comparison `ä` > `b` while the accepted order in German is `ä` < `b`

```
perl -MUnicode::Collate -wE'use utf8; binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"; 
    @s = qw(ä b); 
    say join " ", sort { $a cmp $b } @s;             #-->  b ä
    say join " ", Unicode::Collate->new->sort(@s);   #-->  ä b
'
```

so we need to use `Unicode::Collate` (or a custom sort routine).

Comment: *"The `cmp` used with `sort` can't help with this; it has no notion of encodings and merely compares character by character"* I would have thought that was exactly what you wanted as long as the strings aren't encoded.

Comment: @Borodin  But with strings that come from an encoding other than ascii that will result in a wrong sort?  The linked post is a good example of this problem, I think.

Comment: The main thing to be aware of is that all the Unicode *graphemes* should be normalised to either *composed* or *decomposed* (i.e. as single characters or as basic characters followed by a combining mark). I don't see how the original encoding can affect that.

Answer (score 2):

To open a file saved as UTF-8, use the appropriate layer:

```
open my $FH, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'filename' or die $!;
```

Don't forget to set the same layer for the output.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

binmode *DATA, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
print for sort <DATA>;

__DATA__
Борис
Peter
John
Владимир
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to handle UTF-8 correctly in Perl is to make sure that Perl knows that a certain source or destination of information is in UTF-8. This is done differently depending on the way you get info in or out. If the UTF-8 is coming from an input file, the way to open the file is:

```
open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', "filename" ) or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
```

If you are going to have UTF-8 inside the source of your script, then make sure you have:

```
use utf8;
```

At the beginning of the script.

If you are going to get UTF-8 characters from `STDIN`, use this at the beginning of the script:

```
binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

For `STDOUT` use:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

Also, make sure you read [UTF-8 vs. utf8 vs. UTF8](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8) to know the difference between each encoding name. `utf8` or `UTF8` will allow valid UTF-8 and also non-valid UTF-8 (according to the first UTF-8 proposed standard) and will not complain about non-valid codepoints. `UTF-8` will allow valid UTF-8 but will not allow non-valid codepoint combinations; it is a short name for `utf-8-strict`. You may also read the question [How do I sanitize invalid UTF-8 in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234386/how-do-i-sanitize-invalid-utf-8-in-perl)
.

Finally, following @zdim advise, you may use at the beginning of the script:

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

And other variants as described [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html). That will set the encoding layer for all `open` instructions that do not specify a layer explicitly.

Comment: Or you can use `open pragma` for all standard streams